# HTML Email table borders in iPhone and iPad only

Tags: iphone, html, ipad

I'm making an HTML email and when viewed in iPhone or iPad thin borders appear around cells that contain just HTML content (cells that aren't populated with an image). Any idea how I can get rid of these borders?

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835588/getting-rid-of-default-webkit-borders

Comment: There's no accepted answer though... I tried the three answers to no avail

Comment: read the FAQ. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#link-bounty

Comment: I deleted the original. Not trying to game the system or anything, just looking for an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just come across the same issue and I found a fix but using css - if you have a background color within your email which I assume you do since you are seeing the borders you need to add a extra containing table and set the background color to the "body" color then the inner table will be your content background color

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Seems like this can be achieved with inline styles, no?